# How to get list of files that a program is working with?

Tags: file, io, windows

How to get list of files that a program is working with?
For example, if a program is downloading something, how can I know what and where that file is while downloading?

Comment: Do you mean, the file I/O activity of an application?

Comment: @Dr TJ: small grammar tip: you end many of your questions with "?!". That makes you sound like you're screaming, or are very confused. A single question mark ("?") is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a debugger, OllyDbg is a good one: http://www.ollydbg.de/
For the network activity, use a packet sniffer: Wireshark - http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get this information programmatically, I don't know how to do it. If you are debugging something and want to follow what is going on, check out sysinternals.

Comment: Is it available in windows 7? And yes, i'm trying to achive this programmatically...

Comment: Yes, sysinternals covers pretty much all versions since Windows NT, but it isn't Open Source, so I don't know how to achieve it does.

Comment: Sysinternals is the way to go.  You need Filemon - although I think it's been merged now into a generalised system monitor?